# java epoch time convertor

Tags: java, epoch, influxdb

I have the following date:  `2016-08-08T00:45:02.370294075Z`

I am trying to convert it to epoch using `.getMillis()` but it results in loss of precision: `1470617102370`. My goal is to convert it to influxdb wire format.

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: The result you see _IS_ in milliseconds. The "loss of precision" is because you seem to be expecting nanoseconds output, which a method named `getMillis()` obviously will not provide.

Comment: any other class that i can use to get nanoseconds ? org.joda.time.base dosn't provide any.

Comment: @Cmarv Joda-Time has been supplanted by the java.time framework. The Joda-Time team advises migration to java.time as their project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). The java.time classes have a resolution of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

`2016-08-08T00:45:02.370294075Z` has nanoseconds.

`2016-08-08T00:45:02.370Z` has milliseconds.

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). So up to nine digits in the decimal fraction.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-08-08T00:45:02.370294075Z" ) ;
```

### Milliseconds

[Milliseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) is a coarser granularity than nanoseconds, providing up to three digits of decimal fraction. So [extracting a count of milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) from epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) will of course mean data loss, the truncation of any decimal digits in positions six through nine.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;  // 2016-08-08T00:45:02.370Z
```

### Nanoseconds

The influxdb seems to write a timestamp as a number of nanoseconds from epoch of start of 1970 UTC, though the documentation fails to say so explicitly.

The `Instant` class does not render a count from epoch in nanoseconds, but you can calculate one. An `Instant` is made of a number of while seconds since epoch plus a number of nanoseconds in the fraction of second. So multiply the first by a billion and add the second.

Notice the `L` appended to the one billion to cast the calculation as a `long` rather than an `int`.

```
long nanosecondsSinceEpoch = ( instant.getEpochSecond() * 1_000_000_000L ) + instant.getNano() ;
```